# C# Blazor server problem with loadbalancer connection failed

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr, load-balancing, blazor-server-side

I got following error with blazor server side when using with a loadbalancer:

[image: Blazor signalr connect error]

When I connect directly to the ISS Server's Blazor is connecting correctly.
When I use the loadbalancer it is trying to use the domain of the loadbalancer to connect via websockets, but on loadbalancer no signalR is running.
How do I change the project so it is using not the domain of the loadbalancer and directly connect to the IIS server.

I tried forwarding, but not solved the problem with loadbalancer:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });

 app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

Comment: Did you enable sticky sessions on IIS? Take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-6.0#iis-1